# Convert Text Time to DateTime Remove Leading 0's from Time

Tags: t-sql, casting

I have a time stored in this format as a text in column OPED23OPArrivalTime with a value like this 1846 for time.

I need to use that text value in a datetime column.  The only reason I need to use datetime is that the application the data merges to is a datetime column and then only the time is used in the application but its stripped out at the application level.

When I insert to the table where the data is stored I am doing this but I cannot figure out how to get rid of the leading 0's in the time and the application can't have the leading 0's.

```sql
CASE 
   WHEN [OPED23OPArrivalTime] = '' THEN NULL 
   ELSE CAST(
           STUFF(
              STUFF(
                 RIGHT(CONCAT('000000', [OPED23OPArrivalTime]), 6), 
                 5, 0, ':'
              ), 
              3, 0, ':'
           ) AS datetime
        ) 
END AS 'OPED23OPArrivalTime'
```

**This is my result:**  1900-01-01 00:18:46.000

**I just want it to be** 1900-01-01 18:46

Comment: This 18:46  is minutes and seconds right? @Sherri Ross ?

Comment: Is it possible that the value could be 184602 and that would mean 18:46:02?

Answer (score 0):

If OPED23OPArrivalTime is always four characters in HHmm form (or blank, or null), then

```sql
select try_cast(stuff(OPED23OPArrivalTime, 3, 0, ':') as datetime)
```

If it is sometimes 4 characters in HHmm form, and sometimes six characters in HHmmss form, (or blank, or null) then the main question is what code you think is most readable, I think this is one of the more readable options:

```sql
select try_cast
       (
          case len(@OPED23OPArrivalTime)
             when 4 then stuff(@OPED23OPArrivalTime, 3, 0, ':') 
             when 6 then stuff(stuff(@OPED23OPArrivalTime, 3, 0, ':'), 6, 0, ':')
             else null
          end
          as datetime
       )
```